# Passing variables to all modules

Tags: node.js

I'm building a service which is fragmented across multiple modules that are required when necessary.
I need to access the "request" variable from the router in all my modules.

My current solution (which has been suggested in other threads for passing variables in general) is to pass it to each required module:

> var a_module = require('./a_module')(req);

And exporting each module as functions:

> module.exports = function(req) {
>   ...
>   }

But it is verbose and involves having to export my modules as functions, and only having access to this variable in the scope of the exported functions. Ideally I would like to be able to access the variable across the entire required module.

Is there any other elegant way to do it that I am missing? Like declaring the req variable as a global across the entire application?

Comment: Are you using Express, or just plain NodeJS?

Comment: Node handles multiple requests asynchronously in the same process, unlike PHP. If you set `req` as a global, and handled multiple requests simultaneously, then `req` would get clobbered, so I don't think you should use globals except when they are constant and universal.

Comment: Right, thanks. Another problem: it doesn't seem I can require my module from inside a function - here, the get() function from express. The variable I assign it to is just undefined. It works if I require it outside of the function however. Is there something I am doing wrong? (sorry if I'm missing an obvious point, I'm just getting started with node)

Comment: If you load a module for a request, do you want to unload it after handling the request? Unless you have so many modules that you would run short on memory by loading all of them, I really think that it would be best to load them when the server starts and just keep them. One of the reasons that Node is so fast is that it doesn't restart from scratch for each request; work that is not unique to a particular request is only performed once. I was trying to put together a good answer, but I think that the current system is as good as it gets, at least as far as my skills are concerned.

Comment: If you are running into this kind of problem, I'd ask if you have fragmented your code too far and maybe need to look at your design again.  Modules create namespaces in node and if you are looking to break or circumvent that mechanism then it feels like it's time to review and refactor.

Comment: I have tried using `require` inside of a request handler in the past, and I can confirm that it won't work, but I don't know exactly why. I just `require` everything when the server starts, that way the first request that uses the module doesn't have to wait for it to be loaded. I assume that every module will be used at least once in the lifetime of the server, and I try to do as much work as possible when there isn't a client waiting. Do you have modules that may or may not even be used once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is going to solicit opinions not answers, so it's not a great fit for stack overflow, but here's my $0.02.

You need to step back and ask yourself if you have really written so many modules that need access to a request object. I don't think you have. What you should be writing are functions that take the specific data they need - no more, no less. All these functions almost certainly don't need the entire request. How many of them really need access to every HTTP header, for example? Think of your program as a set of operations on domain objects/data. For example, maybe there's a function that takes a user account record and promotes it from a regular user to an administrator. All that function needs is the user account. It should not be coupled to an HTTP request object.

Just write a bunch of cleanly decoupled functions that take a small number of precise parameters and do something useful with them. This is called "loose coupling". Then organize groups of related functions into a module. This is called "cohesion". Then use some "glue" code to extract the necessary parameters from the HTTP `req` object and pass them as arguments to these functions. These same functions should work for a command line interface or another non-HTTP interface. They will be easier to understand, test, and more long-lived if you code them that way instead of going nuts with every line of every module knowing about the current HTTP `req` object.